# How to get the page number of a given entity

Tags: symfony, pagination, doctrine-orm

I'm displaying a paginated list of entities, and I currently have a normal "page" parameter in the route.
But I would also like to display **the page containing a given entity** (of which I would get the id in the route too). So I need to get the page number related to this entity.

I'm using KnpPaginatorBundle, but I guess there is no such functionality in it.
I've seen the answer with Hibernate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576933/how-to-get-page-number-by-entity-with-nhibernate): is there such index() function in Doctrine 2 ?
Or any way to do this easily ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just counted the number of entities before the current one, it appears that PagniatorBundle doesn't do such thing.